# How to create a double column posts section in laravel using bootstrap . I am having a spacing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

my bootstrap code is like this ,It is just the view part of the code . And with this code i am having the spacing issue as given in the pic.[image: Check the image here]

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                        <div v-for="post in posts">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;position:relative;">
                                <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                                <p>@{{post.content}}</p>
                             <footer class="blockquote-footer">Status By <cite title="Source Title">@{{post.name}}</cite>  <img :src="'{{Config::get('app.url')}}/img/' + post.pic" alt="Card image cap" height="30px" width="30px" style="border-radius:50%;"></footer>
                            </blockquote>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                      </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, you can use card deck if each card is of equal height: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks

If not equal height, you can use card columns: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns

This will automatically take care of spacing issue.